# Tensorflow Custom Training With Phases

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, dropout

I need to create a custom training loop with Tensorflow / Keras (because I want to have more than one optimizer and tell which weights each optimizer should act upon).

Although [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/training_and_evaluation) and [that one too](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough) are quite clear regarding this matter, they miss a **very important** point: how do I predict for training phase and how do I predict for validation phase?

Suppose my model has `Dropout` layers, or `BatchNormalization` layers. They certainly work in a completely different way whether they are in training or validation.

How do I adapt these tutorials? This is a dummy example (may contain one or two pieces of pseudocode):

```
# Iterate over epochs.
for epoch in range(3):


    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

            #model with two outputs
            #IMPORTANT: must be in training phase (use dropouts, calculate batch statistics)
            logits1, logits2 = model(x_batch_train) #must be "training"

            loss_value1 = loss_fn1(y_batch_train[0], logits1)
            loss_value2 = loss_fn2(y_batch_train[1], logits2)

            grads1 = tape.gradient(loss_value1, model.trainable_weights[selection1])    
            grads2 = tape.gradient(loss_value2, model.trainable_weights[selection2])

            optimizer1.apply_gradients(zip(grads1, model.trainable_weights[selection1]))
            optimizer2.apply_gradients(zip(grads2, model.trainable_weights[selection2]))



    # Run a validation loop at the end of each epoch.
    for x_batch_val, y_batch_val in val_dataset:

        ##Important: must be validation phase
            #dropouts are off: calculate all neurons and divide value    
            #batch norms use previously calculated statistics    
        val_logits1, val_logits2 = model(x_batch_val)

        #.... do the evaluations
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just pass a `training` parameter when you call a [`tf.keras.Model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model), and it will be passed down to the layers:

```
# On training
logits1, logits2 = model(x_batch_train, training=True)
# On evaluation
val_logits1, val_logits2 = model(x_batch_val, training=False)
```